# Multiple Subtitles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a title, but am looking to also add two sub-titles. The graph is broken or divided into two sub charts, hence the need for two subtitles.

```
#Add sub-plot
subtitle_string_1=("An In-depth Comparison")
subtitle_string_2=("Immediately Following                                                                 
First Of The Month Following")

plt.suptitle(subtitle_string_1,fontsize=6,x=0.9, y=0.8)
plt.suptitle(subtitle_string_2,fontsize=6,x=.41, y=0.86, color='grey')
```

Is there may a sub_subtitle option? I would really love to have infinite subtitles, talk about power!

Comment: There isn't any built-in support for subtitles in matplotlib, multiple or single. `suptitle` has nothing to do with subtitles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting to add your second string to a new line

```
plt.suptitle(f'(subtitle_string_1}\n{subtitle_string_2}', fontsize=6, x=0.9, y=0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as many times as you need -

`plt.text(x_position, y_position, "Title", color='b', fontsize=12)`:

```
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, "Title", color='b', fontsize=12)
```

or

`ax.text(x_position, y_position, "Title", color='b', fontsize=12)`:

```
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "Title", color='b', fontsize=12)
```